# Manifest V3: chrome.window create method does not open minimized window on giving "state: minimized"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to open a new window in minmized state using [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create) api.
However it does not open in minimized state. Although other options work properly for state but only "minimized" one doesn't.

below is manifest.json.
Note: We are in Manifest V3

```html
{
 ...
   {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" }
  }
  ...
}
```

This is background.js which is trying to open

```html
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'https://www.google.com', state: "minimized" });

// I have tried these as well
// chrome.windows.create({ url: "https://www.google.com", focused: false, state: 'minimized' // });
```

Above snippet does open a new window with a tab in it, but it is **NOT MINIMIZED**.
What I want is to open new minimized window using chrome.windows api.

Comment: It works correctly here, so you either have another extension that changes behavior or your browser overrides it.

Comment: How do I know whether my browser overrides it? Also I have tried it with after removing all of the extensions, it is still same.. opening new active(focused) window. @wOxxOm
this is my chrome browser version -> Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) & OS is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Maybe it's a setting for new windows behavior in Ubuntu's desktop manager.